# C# equivalent of PATINDEX function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, patindex

I have the following SQL Server code which I would like to do in C# code.
The logic is -  if the pattern '%SELECT %FROM% is found in a string called 'x', then I need to return.  The '%' stands for 0 or more characters.

**The part I am not getting is how to translate the first line of code into C#?**

```
 IF PATINDEX('%SELECT %FROM%',  @x ) > 0 
  BEGIN
     RETURN;
  END
```

Comment: You can post some sample code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [regular expresions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) for C# and the match function..

The pattern would be something like

```
.*SELECT .*FROM.*
```

where .* stands for anything other then a new line.

Comment: Thanks your pattern is perfect. One needs to always replace % in SQL Server pattern with .* in C# Regex. That rule is always true it seems.

Comment: The one gotcha is that .* won't match new lines by default.  If you want .* to match new lines then you need to use RegexOptions.Singleline.

Comment: Ok. I will try that out.

Comment: Vulcranos - You are a genius. Your advice is worth a million points. Thanks for that excellent tip on RegexOptions.Singleline